# Node-config global configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, configuration, node-config

I'm using latest node-config. Currently, I have a couple of projects with local configs and another project with general config.

This my current structure:

`ProjectA/configs/{production, staging, integration}`
`ProjectB/configs/{production, staging, integration}`
`Common/configs/{production, staging, integration}`

I need to load `Common/configs` files inside ProjectA and ProjectB using locally defined `NODE_ENV`.

Is this feature currently supported? How to implement something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a maintainer of `node-config`. This feature is not currently supported.

If your config format is JavaScript files (or you are willing to change it). you can use standard Node.js syntax to load the configuration from the common location into the config files for `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.

Comment: That's bad but okay. I've implemented my own configuration for global config